# Issue with upload .pdf file to ftp server - .pdf is created but is empty

Tags: c#, ftp

Here is my code.

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("path");
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("log", "pass");

ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
byte[] fileContent;  //in this array you'll store the file's content

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"pathToFile"))  //'myFile.txt' is the file we want to upload
{
    fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd()); //getting the file's content, already transformed into a byte array
}

using (Stream sw = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    sw.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);  //sending the content to the FTP Server
}
```

.txt files upload correctly with content but .pdf file not. Have no idea where problem is.

Comment: Is it really safe to read a binary file like a PDF as a string into memory?

Comment: So what approach do you recommend ?

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(FIlepath) to get the byte[] of the file and then pass the byte[] to your sw.write()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to reinvent the upload file FTP while there is already [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs) implemented by Microsoft?

> "STOR" means this is a upload in FTP

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("log", "pass");
    client.UploadFile("your_server", "STOR", filePath);
}
```

Comment: It is what i was looking for ! Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. Glad to help you.